Ethical/right to redirect from email based on bronze or gold plan?
After an annual software subscription expires, a user is emailed with renew prices and 3 clickable button options to renew:
Bronze: $10
Silver: $20
Gold: $30

Currently any button click on the email takes the user to a web page, again showing the 3 options and a clickable button for each option

Someone here suggested that if the user chose the Gold button from the email,
they should be taken straight to the step 2 (payment) page

Their rationale was that perhaps the user may change their mind if they initially chose Bronze from the email button but asked a second time on the webpage, might instead go for Silver or Gold


Is it ethical to treat the user differently depending on what button they chose on the email?
UPDATE 1:
There's also a chance that if the user didn't scroll down the email, they wouldn't see the Silver or Gold options since each option has a paragraph of text underneath describing it.

I think it's more of a practical issue than an ethical one. When I receive an email from an e-commerce site with a list of products, I would prefer that when clicking on one of them it takes me directly to the chosen product instead of the general page of the store or the category of the item.

I would direct the user to the page with the chosen option

When clicking on the option, take them to the payment page with the description of what they are purchasing

I would put a title indicating what this page is about: "YOUR CHOICE"

The other options visible but inactive

A link to go to the "pricing page" where all the possible active options appear with the respective information, in this way the user will be able to see all the items that they may not have seen in the email



